# Tensorflow - Better way to expand Tensor to 3D

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have input Tensors of 0-3 dimensions and always want to output to a 3D Tensor (for use with a `tf.einsum` function where I can't use broadcasting), with the axis being filled from inside out. Is there a better way for me to do this than the following (ugly) conditional? I read through `tf.expand_dims`, `tf.reshape`, and `tf.broadcast_to` but couldn't find anything that would allow a dynamic shape based on input Tensors of varying dimensions.

```
import tensorflow as tf


def broadcast_cash_flows(x):
    shape = tf.shape(x)
    dimensions = len(shape)
    return tf.cond(dimensions == 0,
                   lambda: cf_0d(x),
                   lambda: tf.cond(dimensions == 1,
                                   lambda: cf_1d(x),
                                   lambda: tf.cond(dimensions == 2,
                                                   lambda: cf_2d(x),
                                                   lambda: x)))

def cf_0d(x):
    return tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x,0),0),0)

def cf_1d(x):
    return tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x,0),0)

def cf_2d(x):
    return tf.expand_dims(x,0)


cf0 = tf.constant(2.0)
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf0))

cf1 = tf.constant([2.0, 1.0, 3.0])
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf1))

cf2 = tf.constant([[2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
                   [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]])
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf2))

cf3 = tf.constant([[[2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
                    [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]],
                    [[2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
                    [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]]])
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf3))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.expand_dims` is convenient when you want to add one dimension.

`tf.newaxis` is convenient when you want to add multiple dimensions in one operation (instead of calling tf.expand_dims multiple times).

**Modified Code -**

```
import tensorflow as tf

def broadcast_cash_flows(x):
    shape = tf.shape(x)
    dimensions = len(shape)
    if(dimensions == 0):
      return x[tf.newaxis,tf.newaxis,tf.newaxis]
    elif(dimensions == 1):
      return x[tf.newaxis,tf.newaxis,:]
    elif(dimensions == 2):
      return x[tf.newaxis,:,:]
    else:
      return x

cf0 = tf.constant(2.0)
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf0))

cf1 = tf.constant([2.0, 1.0, 3.0])
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf1))

cf2 = tf.constant([[2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
                   [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]])
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf2))

cf3 = tf.constant([[[2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
                    [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]],
                    [[2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
                    [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]]])
print(cf3.shape)
print(broadcast_cash_flows(cf3))
```

**Output -**

```
tf.Tensor([[[2.]]], shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[2. 1. 3.]]], shape=(1, 1, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[2. 1. 3.]
  [3. 2. 4.]]], shape=(1, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
(2, 2, 3)
tf.Tensor(
[[[2. 1. 3.]
  [3. 2. 4.]]

 [[2. 1. 3.]
  [3. 2. 4.]]], shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
```